# Process Builder's Flow Execution!

Tags: process-builder

I have two process builder on same object. Process builder A updates a checkbox field X. the second process builder B fires when X is checked. Now as both the process builders are on same object I cant control their flow of execution. in this case, my Process builder B is never firing. How can i tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Move both actions into a single Process Builder. There's no reason why you should have more than one per object. At the end of the first criteria's execution, you can direct the Process to move on to the next criteria, allowing both to fire. Also, this allows you to control the order of operations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sfdcfox but merging two PBs is not an option for now. I even tried making process builder B as invokable and called it from A after A finishes its actions. However, the process builder B is still not firing. When I checked the debugs, The value of checkbox was still false when the criteria for B was checked.

Comment: @Marc oh, A sets a checkbox that then B checks for? You need to use the Advanced options for re-evaluating Processes after field updates, otherwise each will only see the old values. It is "as if" the processes execute simultaneously. The same rule applies to Workflow Rules as well. See [Reevaluate Records in the Process Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_advanced_reevaluate.htm&type=5) for more info.